# Save mp3 file from a download link on your hosting space using PHP

Tags: php, download

I am fetching data from API of a service provider (Say- `http://serviceprovider.com`).

From several parameter one is MP3 download Link (example- `http://serviceprovider.com/storage/read?uid=475b68f2-a31b-40f8-8dfc-5af791a4d5fa_1_r.mp3&ip=255.255.255.255&dir=recording`)

When I put this download link on my browser it saves it to my local PC.

Now My Problem -

I want to save this MP3 file in one of folder on my hosting space, from where I can further use it for playing using JPlayer Audio.

I have tried `file_get_contents()`, but nothing happened.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

After reading Ali Answer I tried the following code, But still not working fully.

```
// Open a file, to which contents should be written to.
$fp = fopen("downloadk.mp3", "w");
$url = 'http://serviceprovider.com/storage/read?uid=475b68f2-a31b-40f8-8dfc-5af791a4d5fa_1_r.mp3&ip=255.255.255.255&dir=recording';
$handle = curl_init($url);
// Tell cURL to write contents to the file.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);


// Do the request.
$data = curl_exec($handle);

// Clean up.    
curl_close($handle);
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
```

This created the file download.mp3 file on my server but with 0 bytes, i.e. empty.
The url used here is a download link example not a mp3 file that can be played with modern browser directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function file_get_contents is used for reading local files. What you have is an URL and in order to fetch the contents, you need to do a HTTP request in your script. PHP comes with the curl extension, which provides you with a stable library of functions for doing HTTP requests:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Using curl to download your file could be done like this:

```
// Open a file, to which contents should be written to.
$downloadFile = fopen("download.mp3", "w");
$url = "http://serviceprovider.com/storage/read?uid=475b68f2-a31b-40f8-8dfc-5af791a4d5fa_1_r.mp3&ip=255.255.255.255&dir=recording";
$handle = curl_init($url);
// Tell cURL to write contents to the file.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FILE, $downloadFile);
// Follow redirects.
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
// Do the request.
curl_exec($handle);
// Clean up.
curl_close($handle);
fclose($downloadFile);
```

You should probably add some error checking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It create file, but for some reason it does not write anything, i.e. newly created MP3 file on my hosting has 0 bytes. 
I guess the requested url is not returning anything. I told its a download link, not a directly playing link.

Comment: cURL needed to follow redirects. Setting CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION = true solves that.

Comment: @sanjayojha Looking at your edit, you do not need to execute fwrite after the request. cURL writes to the file for you.

Comment: Well, this is funny. This code works for me with the URL given in your edit: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe580c7181cc415c2ff7

Comment: Sorry Ali, I didn't notice your edited answer with (curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);)

Comment: Its working fine. I request you to remove the url from github example for security reason and I will also change it in my edit.
Thank you